# Using Create Random points ignores number of points required in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, random

I am trying to generate around 117 **random points** over patchy forested landscape. As my forested landscape contaisn many polygons (28.000), and I would like to generate specific number of random points, I first `dissolve` my polygon, to create multipart polygon, as speciefied in [ArcGIS help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm).

Example of my very patchy landscape, polygons are forests, white parts are not forested:

[image]

So, to generate random points, I am using as constraints a **multipart polygon** and **minimal distance points**.

However, no matter what required number of points in `number_of_points_or_field` I specify (should by 117 if I quess correctly), I always get back number around 75.

I understand that if my points cannot fit the polygon under minimal distance restriction, there is less of them.

But, I got back the same number of 75 points, even if I set lower number, i.e. 10: `number_of_points_or_field = 10`.

Why does this happen?

Here is my code:

```
# Read input forest data
inForest = os.path.join(inWD, "patchyForest")

# Process: Dissolve feature to create single multipart polygon 
outForestDiss = os.path.join(outDB, "forest_diss")
arcpy.Dissolve_management(in_features = inForest ,
                          out_feature_class = outForestDiss,
                          dissolve_field = "",
                          statistics_fields = "",
                          multi_part = "MULTI_PART",
                          unsplit_lines = "")


# Process: generate random points within the forested area
outPtsName = "randomPoints"
numberPoints = 117  # tried with 10, 75, 117 and I always get back number 75
arcpy.CreateRandomPoints_management(out_path = outDB,
                                    out_name = outPtsName,
                                    constraining_feature_class = outForestDiss,
                                    # constraining_extent = "", # skip this one out
                                    number_of_points_or_field = numberPoints,   
                                    minimum_allowed_distance = distanceBuff * 2,
                                    create_multipoint_output = "POINT")
```

Comment: Try to leave out the constrained extent, if i use the tool this parameter has a specific value, may be a default?

Comment: @AndreasMuller, thank you for suggestion, I have commented the `constraining_extent` out, but I still get back the same result.. 75.. I think the `extent` is deprecated, if I use as a constraint `feature class`. Do you maybe have another suggestions?

Comment: Try exploding your multi-part polygon into single part then run the tool?

Comment: I have odd results when the Spatial Reference for my constraint featureclass and Data Frame do not agree. The tool works with multipart polygons. When the SR's agree, the number of output Points match the number of points specified per singlepart or multipart polygon. Testing with ArcGIS 10.5

Comment: Stacked polygons seem to confuse the Tool, createrandompoints.

Comment: @Hornbydd, my polygon represent patches of forest cover. To get the total number of points, I have dissolved the patches into single layer, as recommended in [ArcGIS help](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-random-points.htm). Without dissolving, the tool creates polygon for every feature. For my forests polygons (~ 28.000 features) I get back the same number of random points.

Answer (score 1):

I have figure out that the `Dissolve` tools is causing issues with improper number of generated points. `Dissolve` tool did not dissolve the whole shapefile as it is supposed too, but instead instead create several linear features. Here is example of the dissolved file, still having several features, but are obviously erroneous due to linear shape:

[image]

Apparently, the use of the `Dissolve` tool within the chain of tools using `arcpy` usually causes troubles [as can be found here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217745/arcgis-dissolve-not-dissolving-records). Neither the adding extra `Field`, populating it with a string, and applied `Dissolve` based on this Field helped.

The only **workaround** I have found was to **manually dissolve the polygon** to generate **exactly 1 multipart polygon**, and than gerenate the correct number of random points.